# Lua: call metatable function from string

Tags: lua

I have this function:

```
function Bootstrap: test()
-- CODE HERE
end
```

I would call this function from it name.

This example works:

```
function callFunc()
    c = "Bootstrap"
    _G[c].test()
end
```

I need to do something like this:

```
function callFunc()
    c = "Bootstrap"
    f = "test"
    _G[name].[f]() -- Bootstrap.test()
end
```

But there is an error:

```
'<name>' expected near '['
```

What I should to do? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.` is unnecessary here. Write `_G[name][f]()`.

`.name` is just a syntactic sugar and is exactly equivalent to `["name"]`, and this place is obviously not where you should use it.

BTW, this has nothing do to with metatables or calling from string. You just access element of one table, than happens to be another table, access element inside that second one, that happens to be function and call it.